# Using div.style.display "block" : "none" to hide/unhide based on 2 checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have 2 `checkboxes` that when clicked should hide/unhide `divs`.

- On the initial page load, if `fundingAvailable` = `false` the Upload should be hidden. (see image)

[image]

---

- When user clicks `Special Handling` checkbox, the Upload should be `hidden`. (see image)

[image]

---

- When user clicks `Override Funding` checkbox, and `fundingAvailable` = `false`, the Upload should be `shown`. (see image)

[image]

---

This is what I have so far:

*jsp*

```
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="cbOverrideFunding" value="true" onclick="fundingAvailableWarning(<%=fundingAvailable%>)" >
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="cbSpecialHandling" value="true" onclick="specialHandlingWarning()">

<% if(!fundingAvailable) { %>
    <TR>
      <TD height="90" valign="top"><BR>
        <div id="fundingAvailable" style="display: block">
           <b><i>The upload functionality has been disabled because the funding is missing.</i></b>
        </div>

        <div id="uploadFile">
         <INPUT name="File1" type="file" id="File1"/>
         <a href="fileUpload()">
           <IMG src="../../images/UploadFile.gif" alt="Upload File">
         </a>
        </div>
<% } %>
<% else { %>
    <div id="uploadFile">
      <INPUT name="File1" type="file" id="File1"/>
      <a href="fileUpload()">
        <IMG src="../../images/UploadFile.gif" alt="Upload File">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="uploadFileSpecialHandling" style="display: none">
      <b><i>The upload functionality has been disabled because of Special Handling.
      </i></b>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

*javascript*

```
function specialHandlingWarning()
{
    if(document.getElementById("fundingAvailable").checked) {
        var div = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
        div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";

        div = document.getElementById("uploadFileSpecialHandling");
        div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }
}

function fundingAvailableWarning(fundingAvailable)
{
    if(!fundingAvailable) {
        var div = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
        div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";

        div = document.getElementById("fundingAvailable");
        div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }
}
```

My problem is that these two divs don't play nice together.

If I select `Special Handling` first, it displays `Upload` page and hides my Warnings.

Comment: Can you try `unset` in place of `none` here => `? "block" : "none";` ?

Comment: @David R did you mean on uploadFile div or all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I would control everything via CSS, so you can just have to change the class name of your most parent element.